# How to find an available spot in an array that has incrementing numbered values?

Tags: php, arrays, iteration, increment

Let's say I have an array of usernames as such:

```
[
'john.doe',
'john.doe1',
'john.doe2',
'john.doe4',
'john.doe5'
]
```

Now a new user registers as john.doe. I have fetched the already existing john.doe's from the DB using a LIKE query and stored in the array above. Then I want to iterate over that array to see which spot is available for the newly registered john.doe.

In this case the available spot would be john.doe3.

I know how to do this using a while loop and simply adding an increment until there's no match.

**Basically I have two questions:**

- Is this the right way of approaching this duplicate username issue altogether?
- I was wondering if maybe there's a better way in lieu of using the while loop?

Comment: Why not just return "The specified name is already taken" and let user choose something else?

Comment: Because the username will be generated based on the user's first and last name .

Comment: then just loop. Technically you can speed up the lookup using binary search, but you unlikely will ever have even more than 10 people with the same names, so using loop is okay. It's not clear though why it's missing `john.doe3`

Comment: With zerk on his latest comment, how did you miss `john.doe3` ? They delete their account or something?

Comment: Yep, he removed his account :) Can you tell me a bit more about the binary search? I know that it's unlikely but I am just very curious on how to do this as airtight as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Nope - better to use an identity token, consider adding a third value such as: `md5('username'.'date')` or `md5('username'.'fullname')` and then you can use this identifier for the specific user.

   The better practice will be to use only the user row id for relations and for  any query and the only step you use the username ( + password) is at login.
2. Here you go:

   ```
   //without while:
   /* NOT TESTED */
   /* $uname -> is the username requested without the duplicate number */
   function find_aspot($arr, $uname) {
       natsort($arr);
       if (empty($arr) || $arr[0] !== $uname) return $uname;
       foreach($arr as $key => $data) {
          $cur = str_replace($uname,'',$data);
          $cur = ($cur === '')?0:intval($cur);
          if (!isset($arr[$key+1])) break;
          $next = intval(str_replace($uname,'',$arr[$key+1]))
          if ($cur+1 !== $next) break;
       }
       return $uname.($cur+1);
   }
   ```

Comment: How would solution 1 work if the username is used for visiting a user's profile? (http://awesomeprofiles.com/john.doe)

Comment: In those kind of social base websites - usernames (nicknames) that are exposed to public, you will always want them to be unique.

Comment: The solutions I suggested are for minimizing usernames collision in the user system, If you are using a unique username policy and you are trying to make alternate username suggestion, you are on the right way. I would have used usernames not unique and add nickname (display name) that has to be unique, or a username = Email address, and add a unique nickname.

Comment: Thanks Shlomi! I'm playing with your suggestions and it feels like I am on the right track now. Just as some background info; my client wants to encourage the use of real names. That's why I want to generate the username based on a user's first and last name upon registration. After registration users will be able to edit their username in their profile settings in case they desire such privacy. I already have that validation available in the app.